# Space between Y-axis and First X tick

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib newbie here.

I have the following code:

```
from pylab import figure, show
import numpy

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plot_data=[1.7,1.7,1.7,1.54,1.52]

xdata = range(len(plot_data))

labels = ["2009-June","2009-Dec","2010-June","2010-Dec","2011-June"]

ax.plot(xdata,plot_data,"b-")

ax.set_xticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

ax.set_yticks([1.4,1.6,1.8])

fig.canvas.draw()

show()
```

When you run that code, the resulting chart has a run-in with the first tick label (2009-June) and the origin.  How can I get the graph to move over to make that more readable? I tried to put dummy data in, but then Matplotlib (correctly) treats that as data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add two limits to the x and y axes to shift the tick labels a bit.

```
# grow the y axis down by 0.05
ax.set_ylim(1.35, 1.8)
# expand the x axis by 0.5 at two ends
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, len(labels)-0.5)
```

the result is

[image]

Comment: Is this code complete? Where is the part to shift the x-axis ticks?

Answer (score 2):

Because tick labels are text objects you can change their alignment.  However to get access to the text properties you need to go through the `set_yticklabels` function.  So add the line:

`ax.set_yticklabels([1.4,1.6,1.8],va="bottom")`

after your `set_yticks` call.  Alternatively if you go through the pylab library directly, instead of accessing the function through the axes object, you can just set that in one line:

`pylab.yticks([1.4,1.6,1.8],va="bottom")`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest change Y axis limits:

```
ax.set_ylim([1.2, 1.8])
```